# How to use batch command "where" and set a variable from a VBScript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, command

I use a batch to execute locally in each client a `robocopy` command, synchronize a folder and then starts an application which has a batch with its own pattern.

My next project is to convert this batch in a VBScript, using it directly from a remote shared folder instead to have the batch stored locally in each client.

Even if I'm not a good VBScript programmer, on the metrics, I'm almost set, but I'm stuck on porting the `where` command to a VBScript.

In my batch file, I execute this command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where /R C:\appfolder startapp.bat /F`) DO (
  SET strAPP=%%F
)
```

In `C:\appfolder` there is installed a software in each client and for some reasons, may be installed in wrong and different patterns, so the common `startapp.bat` may have a different pattern in each client. For this reason the `FOR` instance above help me to create a variable named `%strapp%` which is used later in the batch to start the application.

Now, my VBScript is working using the exact pattern but without this "where command prevention", I would like to have the same feature that batch does, just to prevent that in the future the clients may have again a wrong installation in a non-common pattern.

e.g. in VBS using a strmsg menu, when the user from its client choose the right option, the VBScript starts the application:

```
objShell.Run("%comspec% /K C:\appfolder\startapp.bat & exit"), 1, True

strFlag = True
```

And it works, I tried to add the old `where` command and set a variable adding & in each concatenate commands, all of those in one row with no luck....

e.g.

```
objShell.Run("%comspec% /K FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where /R C:\appfolder startapp.bat /F`) DO (SET strAPP=%%F) & %strapp% & exit"), 1, True

strFlag = True
```

I tried to use double quotes "" with no luck at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VBScript implementation of `where` could look like this:

```
Function Where(fldr, filename)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If LCase(f.Name) = LCase(filename) Then
      Where = f.Path
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Where = Where(sf, filename)
    If Not IsEmpty(Where) Then Exit Function
  Next
End Function
```

The function would be called like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strAPP = Where(fso.GetFolder("C:\appfolder"), "startapp.bat")

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c """ & strAPP & """", 1, True
```

As a side note, it's pointless to start a `CMD` instance with the option `/k` (keep window) when you're going to exit from it anyway. Start it with the option `/c` (close window) and remove the `exit` statement.

As per Ansgar suggestion below, adding method parameter 0, CMD window is hidden

```
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c """ & strAPP & """", 0, True
```

Comment: copied & used **correctly**, @Ansgar's approach just 'works'.

Comment: it works, but it is really slow searching the correct pattern and moreover, it keep a background dos box, I'd like to use Ansgar one, but how could be improved ?
I believe it is related to the application and not to the "where command" by the way, at the moment I do not know how to thankfully both of you, and I'm using in parallel both scripts, I'll decide later which one is reliable.


I'd like also to post the whole script if can be useful for community (I think will not be useful due I'm not a good programmer)

:-)

thank you !!!

Comment: @xer Change the second paramether of the `Run` method to 0 to hide the CMD window. And the `Where` function should be fast enough unless you're searching a UNC path or an extensive folder tree.

Comment: @Ansgar CMD window is now hidden with parameter 0 no UNC path, slow performance is caused by sub-folders with spaces, it is fine.
Your code is part of a long VBscript, I'd like to add a manifesto (a read-me page) plus a code that prevent to be ran twice, I'm sure that code needs amends, but I'd like to share it, may I post the whole code or I'll be OT ?

Comment: @xer Questions and answers on SO should be useful not only to yourself, but to other people as well. Also, the answers should match the questions. In general SO is not the right place for showcasing your work (that's what blogs are for). If the actual answer to your question makes only a small part of your script I'd consider posting an answer with the entire script OT. That's just my opinion, though. You'll probably get a more definitive answer by asking about this on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Ansgar perfect, thanks for your feedback I didn't want to make another mistake :-) will post the complete code with the correct answer, hope you'll reply also on that

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs found:

- expanded `%comspec%` ... Not necessary (thanks to Ansgar Wiechers' comment), it's simply an aspect of my baseless and excessive suspicion of environment variables used in VBScript... *Paranoia* is the right term, I think :)
- inner `"` quotes should be doubled
- parameter name is `%F` from command line; doubled `%` percent sign (`%%F`) in a batch only
- `/V:ON` enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the variable var at execution time.  The %var% syntax expands variables at input (parse) time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR     loop as well as when in a line of `&` concatenated commands
- `usebackq`: missing back quotes in  (`where ...`) do ...
- added `!&echo !strapp!&pause` before `&exit`. This way you could see result while debugging...

Forgotten something? However, all VBScript is as follows:

```
option explicit
Dim strResult: strResult=Wscript.ScriptName

Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd, retrn, params
cmd = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec%") 
params = " /E:ON /V:ON /K FOR /F ""USEBACKQ tokens=*"" %F IN (`where /R C:\appfolder startapp.bat /F`) DO (SET strAPP=%F)&!strapp!&echo !strapp!&pause&exit"
retrn = WshShell.Run(cmd & params, 1, true)

strResult = strResult & vbNewline & cmd
strResult = strResult & vbNewline & params
strResult = strResult & vbNewline & retrn

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit
```

@JosefZ

Thanks for your answer, even if I like the Ansgar solution, I made working yours, I wanted to post it here just in case is useful for someone-else.
At the end, your amended working VBscript (for me) with a where command is this one:

```
option explicit
Dim strResult: strResult=Wscript.ScriptName

Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd, retrn, params
cmd = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%comspec% /C") 
params = "FOR /F ""tokens=* USEBACKQ"" %F IN (`where /R C:\appfolder startapp.bat /F`) DO (SET strAPP=%F) & cmd /C %strapp%"
retrn = WshShell.Run(cmd & params, 1, true)
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: The `Run` method expands environment variables by itself. Expanding `%comspec%` first is not required.

Comment: @Ansgar Okay understood, I'm just newbee for stackoverflow just wanted to let know that I paid attention also to this